# Escaping '.' in dynamically computed regex

Tags: perl

I have a series of replacements I need to make, and I'm storing them in a hash. One of the characters to be replaced is a period (.) and I'm having a tough time escaping it in the regex. Here's a minimum repro:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my %map = ( ';', '1', '\.', '2', );
my $pattern = join('|', sort keys %map);

while (<>) {
    while (s/($pattern)/$map{$1}/) {}
    print;
}

MBA:/Users/ambarish/> ./test.pl 
foo;
foo1
foo.
Use of uninitialized value within %map in substitution iterator at ./test.pl line 7, <> line 4.
foo
```

Escaping it twice ('\.') doesn't help, and escaping it three times makes the error go away, but '.' doesn't get substituted by '2'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `quotemeta` to handle your escaping:

```
my %map = ( ";" => 1, "." => 2 );
my $pattern = join('|', map quotemeta, sort keys %map);
```

Also, you cannot use an escaped period as a hash key and try to find it with an unescaped period. The hash key will contain the backslash, like this:

```
> perl -lwe"%a=('\.',1); use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%a"
$VAR1 = {
          '\\.' => 1
        };
```

Also, of course, if you are using single characters, you can use a character class `[;.]` instead of alternation `|`. This can be dynamically generated using the `qr()` function:

```
my $pattern = join "", sort keys %map;
$pattern = qr([$pattern]);
```